# Which is better, ExpectedException or @Test(expected=

Tags: java, exception, junit

I have code where I check the exceptions in jUnit. I want to know which of the following is a good jUnit practice?

**First**

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void checkNullObject() throws CustomException {
    exception.expect(CustomException.class);
    MyClass myClass= null;
    MyCustomClass.get(null);
}
```

**Second**

```
@Test(expected=CustomException.class)
public void checkNullObject() throws CustomException {
    MyClass myClass= null;
    MyCustomClass.get(null);    
}
```

**EDIT:** Please note that CustomException is a unchecked custom exception. (Though it won't have any impact on this question).

Comment: Either a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785618/in-java-how-can-i-validate-a-thrown-exception-with-junit or primarily opinion based

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends what you want to check in the exception. If all you're doing is checking that the exception is thrown, then using `@Test(expected=...)` is probably the easiest way:

```
@Test(expected=CustomException.class)
public void checkNullObject() throws CustomException {
  MyClass myClass= null;
  MyCustomClass.get(null);
}
```

However, the @Rule ExpectedException has a lot more options, including checking the message, from the [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html):

```
// These tests all pass.
public static class HasExpectedException {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void throwsNothing() {
        // no exception expected, none thrown: passes.
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerException() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsNullPointerExceptionWithMessage() {
        thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("happened?");
        thrown.expectMessage(startsWith("What"));
        throw new NullPointerException("What happened?");
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsIllegalArgumentExceptionWithMessageAndCause() {
        NullPointerException expectedCause = new NullPointerException();
        thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        thrown.expectMessage("What");
        thrown.expectCause(is(expectedCause));
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("What happened?", cause);
    }
}
```

So you can check for the message, the original cause of the exception. For checking the message, you can use matchers, so you can check `startsWith()` and similar.

One reason to use the old style (Junit 3) throw/catch is if you have specific requirements. There aren't many of these, but it can happen:

```
@Test
public void testMe() {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt("foobar");
        fail("expected Exception here");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the `javadoc` link is 404

Comment: Using `@Test`to test for exception has two disadvantages over `@Rule` ExpectedException. 1. you cannot assert cause / message. For example `@Nonnull` did not work as expected and we got an NPE from elsewhere. 2. When we mock exceptions, `@Test(expected)` litters the logs with exception but `@Rule` swallows them if the exception matches.

Comment: only the old style ensures the exception is thrown at the intended place!

Answer (score 0):

The second version is definitely the standard way to do it. The old school way to do it, before Junit 4 looked like:

```
try {
    codeThatShouldThrowException();
    fail("should throw exception");
} catch (ExpectedException expected) {
    //Expected
}
```

Sometimes you might want to revert to this way, for example if you want to assert something about the message in the exception.

Comment: I think even if we want to check something about exception message , we can go with   [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413922/check-errorcode-with-rule-in-junit) . No need to use this try -fail - catch construct

Comment: I specifically said "before Junit 4". Doesn't `this way` refer to a solution which relies on @Rule, which was introduced in Juni 4? https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/introduction-to-junit-4-rules/